# ImportError: Could not import 'authentication.backends.JWTAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am following the example given here : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#accessing-settings.
Once I open the django shell using

```
python manage.py shell
```

and run the following command

```
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
print(api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES)
```

I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django_project\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 177, in import_from_string
    return import_string(val)
  File "C:\django_project\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\django_project\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 225, in __getattr__
    val = perform_import(val, attr)
  File "C:\django_project\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 168, in perform_import
    return [import_from_string(item, setting_name) for item in val]
  File "C:\django_project\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 168, in <listcomp>
    return [import_from_string(item, setting_name) for item in val]
  File "C:\django_project\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 180, in import_from_string
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Could not import 'authentication.backends.JWTAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'authentication.backends'
```

Does someone know what's going on?

P.S: I have a very big django project which is failing with the same error, hence I am pinpointing to only the main setting which is failing in this example.

Comment: Anyone wants to take a shot at this?

Answer (score 0):

The last line in the message is very obvious in explaining why the error is happening:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'authentication.backends'`
There is no authentication/backends.py file in DRF. See the [Github repository](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/master/rest_framework) of DRF. Second, DRF does not offer JWT Authentication out of the box. It does come with TokenAuthentication. Please see https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L151 for details.